# Need help in proving combinatorial identity involving unions, intersections and complements over sets using induction

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, induction

The identity is the following:
$$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (A_i\cup B_i)\right)^C = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^C\cap B_i^C)$$

I must use induction to prove it.

1. Base. Ok, I think I got how to prove base case:

n = 1
$$(A \cup B)^c = (A^c\cap B^c)$$
if x ∈ A U B => x ⊄ (A U B)'

if x ∈ A => x ⊄ A'

if x ∈ A => x ⊄ B'

if x ⊄ A' and x ⊄ B' => x ⊄ (A' Intersection B')

Seems it works.

2. IH

Here I am confused. As I know for induction you need to assume true for n and prove for n+1.

So, I should have the following

$$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1} (A_i\cup B_i)\right)^C = \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (A_i\cup B_i)\right)^C \cap (A_{n+1}\cup B_{n+1})^c$$

And... where should I go now? I am totally confused how to proceed further. 
I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Hagen von Eitzen already gave a hint to solve it by induction, I'll give a direct way, which might be instructive anyway. You want to prove that $$\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (A_i\cup B_i)\right)^C = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^C\cap B_i^C)$$

Notice that:

$$x \in \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n (A_i\cup B_i)\right)^C  \iff x \not\in \bigcap_{i=1}^n (A_i\cup B_i) \iff  \exists \ i \ : x \not\in A_i \cup B_i \iff \\ \iff \exists \ i \ : x \in A_i^C \cap B_i^C \iff x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^C\cap B_i^C) \qquad \square$$

Comment: Thank you a lot.
Could you give me some reference for Hagen von Eitzen hint :) I mean probably some link...

Comment: What part of his hint? The identities that he wrote are very straightforward, he just broke the union and the intersection. For $n = 3$, what he wrote was, for example: $$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 = (A_1 \cap A_2) \cap A_3$$
It is just the way that you look at things. Doing this, you could use the induction on $(A_1 \cap A_2)$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i = X_{n+1}\cap \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} X_i = X_{n+1}\cup \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. Then the case $n+1$ follows readily from $n$ and $2$.